# Obtener link a pagina de autor en WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress

En mi pagina de inicio tengo un sidebar que contiene una pequeña info del autor de la pagina (es como un blog personal) y contiene un boton que dice **leer mi bio** pero Como puedo obtener el link para la pagina del autor del sitio?
Estaba usando esta funcion pero al dar click me muestra la pagina 404...

```
<p><a href="<?php echo the_author_link();?>" class="btn btn-primary btn- 
  sm">Read my bio</a></p>
```

Comment: No tienes que ponerlo dentro de `href`, la función devuelve el link con su href. Otra cosa es que el autor debe tener una página de perfil para que funcione. Prueba así: `<p><? php echo the_author_link();?></p>` Si quieres poner un texto personalizado y clases CSS personalizadas, entonces quizá tengas que hacerlo con `add_filter`, [algo parecido a esto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/201999).

Comment: <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author() ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>

Hola, este código debería funcionar.
puedes leer más en  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/